# Django Haystack SearchQuerySet order_by returning no results

Tags: django, django-haystack, searchqueryset

I have Haystack working in "Old urls.py" below. When I try to order my search results using [order_by](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html?highlight=order_by#SearchQuerySet.order_by) on the model field 'canonical_school_score', as seen in "New urls.py," I keep getting no search results. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

```
# Old urls.py
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
    )

# New urls.py
    from haystack.views import search_view_factory, SearchView
    from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
    sqs = SearchQuerySet().order_by('-canonical_school_score')

    urlpatterns = patterns('',        
        url(r'^search/', search_view_factory(
            view_class=SearchView,
            template='search/search.html',
            searchqueryset=sqs
        ), name='haystack_search'),
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was that 'canonical_school_score', while a model field, was not part of the search index, search_indexes.py.

Makes sense in retrospect. Hopefully this helps others not repeat the same mistake.